# customization of references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, varioref

Im working with a tex document with a lot of references. Im using:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{varioref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=title,linkcolor=title,urlcolor = title}
```

Even so every reference has figure/table etc. in front of the numbering, by my professor thinks the references are too identical. Is there any way i can customize the references so `\cref{fig:1}` becomes figure 1.1 in **blue**, tables references becomes **red**, algorithm becomes **bold** algorithm **1.1** equation becomes with [ ], and a final reference uses a different `**textsize/style**`?

How to customize the references depended on what you are referring to?

Comment: Possibly irrelevant, but `varioref` should go before `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `\creflabelformat` and `\crefname` definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\creflabelformat{figure}{\color{red} \textbf{#1#2#3}}
\crefname{figure}{\color{blue} figure}{figures}
\creflabelformat{equation}{[#1#2#3]}
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{eqs. #3[#1]#4--#5[#2]#6}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{figure}[h]

        \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Example image A\label{fig:fig1}}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]
    \cref{fig:fig1}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:eq1}
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation}

    \cref{eq:eq1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I only changed the figure and equation, I leave the table and algorithm as an exercise for you :) . 
More about this in [section 4 of the cleverref user guide](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).